# C# Regex find string between two different pairs of strings

Tags: c#, regex, string, string-search

Using C# RegEx, I am trying to find text enclosed by two distinct pairs of words, say, start1....end1, and start2...end2. In my example below I would like to get: text1, text2, text11, text22.

```
string str = "This start1 text1 end1. And start2 text2 end2 is a test. This start1 text11 end1. And start2 text22 end2 is a test.";

Regex oRegEx = new Regex(@"start1(.*?)end1|start2(.*?)end2", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
MatchCollection oMatches = oRegEx.Matches(sHTML);
if (oMatches.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (Match mt in oMatches)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(mt.Value);     //the display includes the start1 and end1 (or start2 and end2)
        Console.WriteLine(mt.Groups[1].Value); //the display excludes the start1 and end1 (or start2 and end2) or displays an empty string depending on the order of pattern.
    }
}
```

`mt.Groups[1].Value` in the above code correctly displays text1, text11 if the pattern is `@"start1(.*?)end1|start2(.*?)end2"` but it displays empty strings for text2, and text22. On the other hand if I change order in the pattern to `@"start2(.*?)end2|start1(.*?)end1"`, it correctly displays text2, text22 but displays empty strings for text1 and text11. What needs to change in my code?
This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) explains something about when a group returns empty string but I am still not getting the desired results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give name to group.

```
start1(?<val>.*?)end1|start2(?<val>.*?)end2
```

And get value as:

```
mt.Groups["val"].Value
```

The original problem is that without names the group between `start1` and `end1` has index `1`, and group between `start2` and `end2` has index `2`, as you can see from the following picture:
[image: Regular expression visualization]

Or **another** solution is to use regex like:

```
(?<=start([12])).*?(?=end\1)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/d_7YhQfZ74SPm7hh)

And then in your code:

```
Console.WriteLine(mt.Value);
```

will display the required content.

Comment: @Ulugbek, thank you very much for helping me and most likely many other readers of this post. Thanks also for explaining the problem  and providing a solution. Per your suggestion, I gave a name to the group and it works now.